# Delete Solution From Pyomo Model or (reset all variables to empty)

Tags: pyomo

I would like to know if there is a way to return a Pyomo Concrete Model to its initial state, when the value of the variables is None.

The reason I want to do this is that I have a multi-objective problem and I want to try to solve the problem with two different methods (Weighting Method and Lexicographic Sorting) in the same script.

When I use the Weighting Method, I get a solution for my model and the values of the decision variables are defined.

Then, when I solve the problem with Lexicographic Ordering, the model already has the solutions defined, and the results provided by Lexicographic Ordering are affected by these values, since the solutions reached by Lexicographic Ordering if run in a separate script are different.

Comment: A couple of questions may help figure out what is going on here:  1.  Is the model linear?  2.  When you have 2 different solutions when employing Lexicographic Ordering, is the objective *value* the same (multiple optimal solutions)?  3.  If not, what does the solver status say for both solves?

Comment: Hi @AirSquid. First of all, the model has one quadratic objective and four linear objectives. When I use the Lexicographic Ordering, the final result is practically identical in both cases, there are changes from the fourth or fifth decimal place, even so it would be possible that there are bigger differences, because the problem has multiple solutions. The main differences are in the first iterations of the Lexicographic Ordering, since it seems that in one case it starts with the decision variables taking the values calculated by the Weights Method and in the other it does not.

Comment: @Air Squid So what I want is to avoid that the Lexicographic Ordering starts with initial values from de Weights Method .
Finally, to add, that The status of the solver in both cases is 'ok'. Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still actual, but maybe you could use the midpoint or zero initializer preprocessing transformations for this:

> https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contributed_packages/preprocessing.html#pyomo.contrib.preprocessing.plugins.init_vars.InitMidpoint

Another solution would be to clone your model and solve two separate model instances.